# WPF tiles animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

i'am trying to build some animation for tiles in my WPF project home page.

i want to do something like this [sample](http://metro-webdesign.info/#&home)

particularly the "looking for wordpress version" and "Full download" ones

**1. Shadow**

i try

```
<DropShadowEffect x:Key="MyEffect" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Red" Opacity="1" BlurRadius="20" Direction="0"/>
```

for shadow effect but even the inner color change tending to violet

**2. for text animation i use this**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtStateRunning" Background="Crimson" Text="text" Margin="10">
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="textAnimation">
                    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtStateRunning"  Duration="0:0:5"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Text" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="False" >
                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="text 1"   KeyTime="0:0:0" />
                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="text 2"  KeyTime="0:0:0.5" />
                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="text 3" KeyTime="0:0:2" />
                        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame Value="text 4" KeyTime="0:0:3.5" />
                    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

but the effect is instantaneous while i search for the entering effect

**3. in the "download" of the example the color change gradually, how can be done?**

Comment: use [ColorAnimation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.coloranimation(v=vs.110).aspx) for gradual color change.

Comment: good, one solved. now remain text enter and shadow

Comment: what is the question for text enter and shadow? I saw only one `?`

Comment: just marked with bold the 3 question